# Use picture border CSS in tag <td>?

Tags: php, html, css, css-selectors

I don't know what the problem is, I bang my head for half an hour... Does not display a border at all. Even when I insert any image, anywhere, it doesn't work.

HTML file

```
<table><tr><td class="transparent text_right"><img class="right_picture *border_clipart*" src="slika/prase.png"></td><td class="text_right transparent table_right_text justify"> Simple text </td></tr></table>
```

---

CSS file

```
border_clipart{
border: 10px solid transparent; 
border-image: url(slika/border_right.png) round;
border-image-slice: 50%;
  }
```

Comment: Inspect your element/image in your browser and make sure the class has actually been applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by 3 typos and one bad use.

**1st & 2nd Typo:**

`<img class="right_picture *border_clipart*" src="slika/prase.png">`

your class name of `*border_clipart*` is invalid because of the `*` at the front and the end of the class name. You have to delete it to following line:

`<img class="right_picture border_clipart" src="slika/prase.png">`

**3rd Typo:**

`border_clipart { border: 10px solid transparent;  border-image: url(slika/border_right.png) round; border-image-slice: 50%; }`

A class name always has to start with a dot and an ID name with a hash. In this case you forgot the dot. Simply put the dot at the front of the classname:

`.border_clipart { border: 10px solid transparent;  border-image: url(slika/border_right.png) round; border-image-slice: 50%; }`

**Bad use:**

You used a transparent color for the border. In this case you won't see the color and it will rather work as margin which you should have used then. For demonstration I changed it to red:

```css
.border_clipart{
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-image: url(slika/border_right.png) round;
  border-image-slice: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="transparent text_right">
      <img class="right_picture border_clipart" src="slika/prase.png">
    </td>
    <td class="text_right transparent table_right_text justify"> 
      Simple text 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If your problem is solved, then please delete your question instead of upvoting or marking this as an anwser. Questions caused by typos have no value on SO.

Comment: I suppose the `*` in `*border_clipart*` are there to emphasize that OP has added the class there